# MySQL Trigger usage : if column is null set other column null

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I realize the following in MySQL with Triggers: 
When value of some column is null -> set other column values to null
and 
when value of some column is not null -> set other column values to null

table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE variations (  
id int(10) NOT NULL, 
x1 int(10) NOT NULL, 
x2 int(10), 
x1_option1 BOOL, 
x2_option1 BOOL, 
x1_option2 varchar(10), 
x2_option2 varchar(10)
);
```

The idea is that we have 2 Elements, `x1`and `x2`. While `x1`is mandatory, `x2`is optional and can be null. Both, x1 and x2 have two options: `x1_option1` , `x2_option1`, `x1_option2` and `x2_option2`.
The first rule should be that when x2 is null, both options for x2 (`x2_option1`, `x2_option2`) must also be null.
My attempt:

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER check_null_x2 BEFORE INSERT 
ON variations
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.x2 IS NULL THEN 
SET NEW.x2_option1 = NULL;
SET NEW.x2_option2 = NULL;
END IF;
END$$
```

Throws Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

Can you please help me figuring out whats wrong? I just dont understand what '' means.

The second rule should be that there can only be one of the two options selected. that means if `x2_option1` is NOT NULL, `x2_options2` must be NULL. In general i think this can be done the same way as the first rule. My question: how can i do multiple 'IF', 'ELSE IF' etc in one trigger?

Comment: What happens if you substitute `END$$` with `END` ?

Comment: @Alexander nothing changes, still the same error.

Comment: @Jbartmann in both situation you want to set column values to null ?

Comment: @Ashishjagtap yes, after i checked if some column is null / not null.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is syntax for trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
             SET NEW.amount = 0;
         ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
            SET NEW.amount = 100;
         END IF;
    END;//
 delimiter ;
```

...and your code is here:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER check_null_x2 BEFORE INSERT ON variations
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.x2 IS NULL THEN 
            SET NEW.x2_option1 = NULL;
            SET NEW.x2_option2 = NULL;
        END IF;
    END$$ -- THIS LINE SHOULD BE: "END;//"
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT:**
The official [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) says the following:

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ; delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the below sql statement is giving error.

Answer (score 2):

you seem to have ";" set as DELIMETER, which causes the query to execute once it sees a ";". try changing it first:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE 
TRIGGER check_null_x2 BEFORE INSERT 
ON variations
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.x2 IS NULL THEN 
SET NEW.x2_option1 = NULL;
SET NEW.x2_option2 = NULL;
END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `XXXXXX` BEFORE INSERT ON `XXXXXXXXXXX` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF ( NEW.aaaaaa IS NULL ) THEN 
SET NEW.XXXXXX = NULL;
SET NEW.YYYYYYYYY = NULL;
END IF;
END


Worked for me....
```